# having problems defining a sub-layout, cannot find the proper way to give an element all the height available

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

i have a main layout defined as

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper-mobile {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.wrapper-web {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

A simple fixed header and footer with a scrollable main area ( content class ), in the mobile version or just fixed header and main otherwise.

```
<div class="wrapper-mobile">
    <header>header area</header>
    <main class="content">main area</main>
    <section>footer area</section>
</div>
```

Now, inside this main area, I would like to define another layout, where a "actions" section sits just above the footer ( if mobile ), while the top area fill all the rest of the available space.

I have tried to defined this sub-layout as grid also

```
.sub-layout {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 80px;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

or with flexbox, but the actions section

```
<div class="sub-layout">
    <div>main</div>
    <section>actions</section>
</div>
```

gets pushed beyond sight, only visible if scrolling down.
what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with nested grids and a media query, I chose breakpoint 768px, edit accordingly in the CSS. Setup using a mobile first approach

You can click on the red header to toggle the purple actions on/off

```css
/* START: IGNORE THESE STYLES */
body { color: white; font: 16px sans-serif; margin: 0 }
header { background-color: red }
main { background-color: green }
nav { background-color: purple }
footer { background-color: blue }
header, nav, footer, main .main-inner { padding: .5rem 1rem }
main>*:first-child {  margin-top: 0 } main>*:last-child {  margin-bottom: 0 }
/* END: IGNORE THESE STYLES */



/* START STYLES FOR ANSWER */
.wrapper-mobile {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.wrapper-mobile main, .wrapper-mobile main .main-inner { min-height: 0 }

.wrapper-mobile main { display: grid }
.wrapper-mobile main .main-inner { overflow-y: auto }

.wrapper-mobile.no-actions main nav { display: none }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper-mobile { grid-template-rows: auto 1fr }
  .wrapper-mobile footer { display: none }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-mobile">
  <header onclick="this.parentElement.classList.toggle('no-actions')">header area</header>
  <main>
    <div class="main-inner">
      <p>Condimentum dui habitasse massa vestibulum lectus eu nisl libero sagittis at donec duis per urna tristique. Imperdiet pharetra magna adipiscing turpis a dictum a a suspendisse nibh torquent parturient cursus parturient iaculis ultricies ullamcorper
        montes. A molestie a a nullam accumsan odio bibendum mi id suspendisse dis ullamcorper volutpat fermentum mi consectetur elit ultricies parturient parturient a fames nisl a a aptent. A faucibus consectetur magnis nibh pretium a in curae fringilla
        eget gravida donec dolor fringilla ac condimentum cras eu.</p>
      <p>Commodo massa convallis consectetur a mi nisi scelerisque volutpat dis at purus vestibulum justo adipiscing montes orci magna ut faucibus convallis id nullam ridiculus ultricies. Vehicula sociosqu nec parturient leo vestibulum porta suspendisse
        pharetra a et senectus sagittis auctor ac taciti at adipiscing. Proin aenean aenean vestibulum id a scelerisque id parturient a cubilia fermentum curae cursus senectus facilisis cursus nostra. Velit aliquet ut posuere venenatis tempor ac nascetur
        mollis sit dui tempor eget enim ullamcorper porta morbi ad ante a cubilia malesuada integer. Scelerisque condimentum at penatibus facilisi ligula donec cras fames mi penatibus ullamcorper adipiscing nibh purus parturient condimentum. Primis congue
        scelerisque adipiscing gravida condimentum dapibus suscipit rutrum posuere felis a cras parturient pretium torquent justo vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum nam curae massa ac suspendisse scelerisque justo consectetur parturient nam bibendum parturient egestas faucibus potenti. Vestibulum a est sit fringilla sit ipsum sapien pharetra vestibulum rhoncus vehicula accumsan vestibulum magna porttitor
        accumsan scelerisque nulla id. Id imperdiet conubia adipiscing proin ullamcorper natoque molestie libero blandit justo curabitur vestibulum id a lobortis a a ullamcorper dis mi arcu fames a non condimentum sit scelerisque.</p>
      <p>Nec praesent litora scelerisque nibh pretium venenatis lorem quam posuere interdum semper a vitae eu condimentum tristique duis dapibus parturient suspendisse taciti hendrerit tempor eros a cum ac. Nisl himenaeos dictumst et parturient tristique
        adipiscing adipiscing scelerisque libero suspendisse adipiscing aenean parturient adipiscing at amet a parturient venenatis etiam velit est cursus fermentum. Eu magna interdum diam a vulputate a blandit mollis ullamcorper id dictumst magnis feugiat
        in dis consectetur suspendisse integer mus turpis adipiscing id vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Condimentum dui habitasse massa vestibulum lectus eu nisl libero sagittis at donec duis per urna tristique. Imperdiet pharetra magna adipiscing turpis a dictum a a suspendisse nibh torquent parturient cursus parturient iaculis ultricies ullamcorper
        montes. A molestie a a nullam accumsan odio bibendum mi id suspendisse dis ullamcorper volutpat fermentum mi consectetur elit ultricies parturient parturient a fames nisl a a aptent. A faucibus consectetur magnis nibh pretium a in curae fringilla
        eget gravida donec dolor fringilla ac condimentum cras eu.</p>
      <p>Commodo massa convallis consectetur a mi nisi scelerisque volutpat dis at purus vestibulum justo adipiscing montes orci magna ut faucibus convallis id nullam ridiculus ultricies. Vehicula sociosqu nec parturient leo vestibulum porta suspendisse
        pharetra a et senectus sagittis auctor ac taciti at adipiscing. Proin aenean aenean vestibulum id a scelerisque id parturient a cubilia fermentum curae cursus senectus facilisis cursus nostra. Velit aliquet ut posuere venenatis tempor ac nascetur
        mollis sit dui tempor eget enim ullamcorper porta morbi ad ante a cubilia malesuada integer. Scelerisque condimentum at penatibus facilisi ligula donec cras fames mi penatibus ullamcorper adipiscing nibh purus parturient condimentum. Primis congue
        scelerisque adipiscing gravida condimentum dapibus suscipit rutrum posuere felis a cras parturient pretium torquent justo vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum nam curae massa ac suspendisse scelerisque justo consectetur parturient nam bibendum parturient egestas faucibus potenti. Vestibulum a est sit fringilla sit ipsum sapien pharetra vestibulum rhoncus vehicula accumsan vestibulum magna porttitor
        accumsan scelerisque nulla id. Id imperdiet conubia adipiscing proin ullamcorper natoque molestie libero blandit justo curabitur vestibulum id a lobortis a a ullamcorper dis mi arcu fames a non condimentum sit scelerisque.</p>
      <p>Nec praesent litora scelerisque nibh pretium venenatis lorem quam posuere interdum semper a vitae eu condimentum tristique duis dapibus parturient suspendisse taciti hendrerit tempor eros a cum ac. Nisl himenaeos dictumst et parturient tristique
        adipiscing adipiscing scelerisque libero suspendisse adipiscing aenean parturient adipiscing at amet a parturient venenatis etiam velit est cursus fermentum. Eu magna interdum diam a vulputate a blandit mollis ullamcorper id dictumst magnis feugiat
        in dis consectetur suspendisse integer mus turpis adipiscing id vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Condimentum dui habitasse massa vestibulum lectus eu nisl libero sagittis at donec duis per urna tristique. Imperdiet pharetra magna adipiscing turpis a dictum a a suspendisse nibh torquent parturient cursus parturient iaculis ultricies ullamcorper
        montes. A molestie a a nullam accumsan odio bibendum mi id suspendisse dis ullamcorper volutpat fermentum mi consectetur elit ultricies parturient parturient a fames nisl a a aptent. A faucibus consectetur magnis nibh pretium a in curae fringilla
        eget gravida donec dolor fringilla ac condimentum cras eu.</p>
      <p>Commodo massa convallis consectetur a mi nisi scelerisque volutpat dis at purus vestibulum justo adipiscing montes orci magna ut faucibus convallis id nullam ridiculus ultricies. Vehicula sociosqu nec parturient leo vestibulum porta suspendisse
        pharetra a et senectus sagittis auctor ac taciti at adipiscing. Proin aenean aenean vestibulum id a scelerisque id parturient a cubilia fermentum curae cursus senectus facilisis cursus nostra. Velit aliquet ut posuere venenatis tempor ac nascetur
        mollis sit dui tempor eget enim ullamcorper porta morbi ad ante a cubilia malesuada integer. Scelerisque condimentum at penatibus facilisi ligula donec cras fames mi penatibus ullamcorper adipiscing nibh purus parturient condimentum. Primis congue
        scelerisque adipiscing gravida condimentum dapibus suscipit rutrum posuere felis a cras parturient pretium torquent justo vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum nam curae massa ac suspendisse scelerisque justo consectetur parturient nam bibendum parturient egestas faucibus potenti. Vestibulum a est sit fringilla sit ipsum sapien pharetra vestibulum rhoncus vehicula accumsan vestibulum magna porttitor
        accumsan scelerisque nulla id. Id imperdiet conubia adipiscing proin ullamcorper natoque molestie libero blandit justo curabitur vestibulum id a lobortis a a ullamcorper dis mi arcu fames a non condimentum sit scelerisque.</p>
      <p>Nec praesent litora scelerisque nibh pretium venenatis lorem quam posuere interdum semper a vitae eu condimentum tristique duis dapibus parturient suspendisse taciti hendrerit tempor eros a cum ac. Nisl himenaeos dictumst et parturient tristique
        adipiscing adipiscing scelerisque libero suspendisse adipiscing aenean parturient adipiscing at amet a parturient venenatis etiam velit est cursus fermentum. Eu magna interdum diam a vulputate a blandit mollis ullamcorper id dictumst magnis feugiat
        in dis consectetur suspendisse integer mus turpis adipiscing id vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
    <nav>actions</nav>
  </main>
  <footer>footer area</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, in the non mobile version, the footer ceases to exist, and the actions section ( if needed in the page ) acts as the new footer, fixed also.
i posted the current behavior off the mobile, on the other comment, i'll leave it here too. i would like that the actions section to get fixed, while having a scrollable content area above.

[link](https://i.postimg.cc/j5tckv5q/Recording-2022-07-12-at-10-57-49.gif)

Comment: @rezanov so on mobile you want `fixed header`, `scrollable main` and `fixed actions + footer` -- then on desktop you want `fixed header` and `main`

Comment: yes, but the "actions" section might not be required, imagine i have a table with some sort of pagination, i should not be able to scroll down to press Next or Previous, these actions should be avaible and visible always, ex. But yes, on mobile, `fixed header + footer`. `actions` if required, `fixed also` with a `scrollable main`. 

when not mobile, there is no footer. everyting else applies.

Comment: @rezanov I updated the answer, basically if there is not meant to be actions then add class `no-actions` to the `wrapper-mobile` -- for the example if you click on the red header it will toggle this class for you so you can see the difference

Comment: just a side note. do you think its possible to keep the actions section inside the main area ?

Comment: @rezanov so actions inside the main element but still so it’s visible  all the time?

Comment: @rezanov I updated the snippet, you will need to wrap the content of the main element in `<div class="main-inner">...</div>` and then the actions will be outside of this div but still within the main element

Comment: nice ) this is it ! what is purpose of setting something with a `min-height: 0` ?

Comment: @rezanov grid children have a `min-height: auto` set by default which will cause the  grid to resize beyond `height: 100vh` -- so `min-height: 0` is used to override the default and keep the grid row layout contained in the set height

Comment: ok, gets to cheat sheet. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the height of `.wrapper-mobile` and `.sub-layout`. You have given `height: 100vh` to both of them.
Try to reduce height of `.sub-layout`.

Comment: i gave a `min-height: 2rem;` to `.sub-layout`, still, if main area geets too big, the actions section gets pushed beyond sight

Comment: current behavior 
[link](https://i.postimg.cc/j5tckv5q/Recording-2022-07-12-at-10-57-49.gif)